# interface / inheritance model django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to modeling the following in Django but I am having troubles

```
City:
     name : Str
     belongs_to_providence : Providence

Providence:
     name : Str
     belongs_to_country : Country

Country:
     name : Str
     language : Str

Proponsal:
     title : Str
     affects_to : City | Providence | Country
```

I tried to do this using an abstract model , like the following :

```
# account/models.py
class CommonLocationInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Country(CommonLocationInfo):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Providence(CommonLocationInfo):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="belongs_to_country", null=True)

class City(CommonLocationInfo):
    providence = models.ForeignKey(Providence, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="belongs_to_providence", null=True)

class Proponsal(models.Model):
     affects_to = models.ManyToManyField(CommonLocationInfo)
```

but is not working , it tells me the following

> Field defines a relation with model 'CommonLocationInfo', which is
>   either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: I think that the error message is quite clear! What you want to do is not possible. Don't forget that the models are an abstraction over your database and you can't have a foreign key to multiple tables. A possible solution would be to use a generic relation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations